# model object is reflecting object instead of title

Tags: python, django, django-models

In django when ever I am trying to view my `[Post.objects.all()]` its results `Post:Post Object` instead of `Post: title`.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shL4b.png)

here is my models.py

```
    from django.db import models
# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    post_title=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False)
    post_content=models.TextField()
    creation_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,auto_now_add=True)
    lastDate_modified=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,auto_now_add=False)

def __str__(self):
            return self.post_title
```

and the output is `>>> Post.objects.all()
[<Post: Post object>, <Post: Post object>]`

Comment: you will need to supply some more code, its impossible to answer this question

Comment: It looks like you are wanting to override `__repr__` rather than `__str__`: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#repr

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a **str** method for your Post model as follows:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
            blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Override the **str** method might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you are not using `print`.

```
def __repr__(self):
    return self.post_title
```

`print` will call `__str__`, where as console output will be `__repr__`

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it was your cut and paste but the indentation is wrong in your code

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_title=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False)
    post_content=models.TextField()
    creation_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,auto_now_add=True)
    lastDate_modified=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,auto_now_add=False)

def __str__(self):
            return self.post_title
```

It should be:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_title=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False)
    post_content=models.TextField()
    creation_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,auto_now_add=True)
    lastDate_modified=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,auto_now_add=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post_title
```